# Set Distribution group notes

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

I'm trying to change the distribution group notes via powershell on a Exchange 2010 Server.

**This is the way how to set the notes during creating a new group:**

```
New-DistributionGroup "G_test" -Notes "TESTTEST"
```

**But how to set the notes after creating the group?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the solution: It looks like Exchange does not distinguish between the group types in some points. So you have to use `Set-Group` (Not `Set-DistributionGroup`) to change the notes attribute.

**Example**

```
Set-Group –identity G_test –Notes “For chess lovers!”
```